# How to implement In-App Purchase gifting?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I originally thought it was impossible to gift In-App Purchase items, until I saw this in Diptic.

[image]
[image]

Update: I simply "installed" this app and though it is Free so I inferred the gift is for its In-App Purchase. However I forgot I downloaded this app before so "Install" does not mean it is free and the gift is in fact the app per se not its In-App Purchase items. Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

That is gifting the base $0.99 app. That is not gifting any in-app purchases. Apple does not provide any way to gift in-app purchases <s>nor any way to provide promo codes for in-app purchases</s>.

Support for in-app purchase promo codes is now supported.

Comment: Might it be possible now with IOS 11?

https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev50869de4a

"For in-app purchase promo codes, the app will automatically download if the app is free and not currently installed on the customer's device. If the app is paid, customers will need to download the app in order to redeem the in-app purchase."

Comment: @Wayne Yes, Apple did add IAP promo code sometime since I originally wrote this answer. I have no idea when that was. I don't know of gifting an IAP is supported. Have a look at the App Store app and check.

Answer (score 0):

However, you can write your own custom logic within your app to give your in app purchases away free for a period of time.

Comment: You will most likely be rejected when going to store, Apple forbids purchases other than using Apples mechanisms.